# Laravel 5 : How do I retrieve 10 records of each kind of data in a column?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I realise in Laravel 5 Eloquent there is a function called groupBy. I usually used it like so

```
->groupBy('rating');
```

Let's say in rating column, there are 3 types of ratings in integer : `1,2 and 3`How do I limit it to 10 records for each kind of rating? Preferably using Eloquent but if that's not possible, I'll still accept query builder method.

Comment: All methods available on the query builder are also available when querying Eloquent models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Union](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#unions) should work:

```
$type1 = Model::whereType(1)->take(10);
$type2 = Model::whereType(2)->take(10);
$type3 = Model::whereType(3)->take(10);

$types = $type1->union($type2)->union($type3)->get();
```

Comment: Erm, isn't that like querying four times? Is it possible to just get the answers in a single query?

Comment: take() method will not execute the query, as far as I remember, it returns a query builder instance. Only the get() call (on the last line) will execute the query. @limonte: your link is totally different of what we are doing here. Eloquent is an ORM and the number of executed queries only depends on its implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not getting your question wrongly, your question mysql solution would be [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12114021/1728836)

But when we convert our desire query to laravel, so its will look alike:

```
$Rating1 = Model::whereRating(1)->take(10);
$Rating2 = Model::whereRating(2)->take(10);
$Rating3 = Model::whereRating(3)->take(10);
$result = Model::unionAll($Rating1)->unionAll($Rating2)->unionAll($Rating3)->get();
```

And its also one query not multiple as per laravel 4.2 docs, If you still confuse to implement it, let me know.